# General rule for the sub woofer

Tags: rule

When mixing 5.1 films, is there a rule of thumb or general rule for what gets sent to the sub woofer and how much of it?

I know there are controls on some plug-ins that let you choose what the crossover is and I was wondering if there is a generally accepted setting that is standard in the industry that you set it at, or if it's just by listening and seeing what sounds right in the mix?

I apologize if this is a newbie question - but I figured I'd ask since no-one else has and I might be out of the loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes put a lo-pass filter at 100 Hz on the sub, not always but that depends on the material I send to the sub.

Generally I send LFE effects to the sub and i spill some of other sounds I want to have that lo end too. For instance I almost always send music to the sub, not too much, but enough to make it sound rich and full. If I have a sound with a lot of nice lo frequency information in it, I will probably send some to the sub.

Generally you can't trust the level of the subwoofer too much, because it varies from cinema to cinema. It depends a lot on the size of the room, so if you are in a huge cinema with 1000-2000 seats you will normally get a lot more percieved bass than you get in a smaller room. So if you are playing it soft in a small editing room, it may get really loud in a big cinema, but even if you are making soft sub sends on a mixing stage, it may still get really loud in a big cinema.

The only rule I have is that I try not to rely too much on the sub. I use it very actively, sometimes nearly all of the time, but the film needs to sound good even if you turn off the subwoofer. The point needs to be put across even without the subwoofer, so you need to use the front speakers as well.

If you watch a DVD on a tv set in stereo, the DVD-player discards the LFE channel before downmixing to stereo.

My first feature film as sound designer went to the Cannes film festival in 2003, where it was shown in the "Semaine de la Critique". This isn't the main programme, so it wasn't shown in the big, Dolby-approved, cinemas, but instead it was shown in a small art cinema.

The cinema was lousy, with a loud air conditioning and a film operator who initially refused to play the film at Dolby level 7. The theater couldn't even play back Dolby Digital, so wa had to go with Dolby SR instead.

At one point in the film, I had made a soft sub "wash" or "whoosh" in a quiet scene, which only played in the LFE channel. In the SR version it was of course a part of the stereo mix, but in this lousy cinema, they had no subwoofer, so instead of the warm bass sound washing over you, you would only hear the soundtrack get thin as all of the energy of the soundtrack was taken up by a sound you couldn't hear.

A couple of months later I saw it in the biggest cinema in Copenhagen with 1100 seats, in Dolby Digital, at Dolby level 7, and the soft sub bass sound was there again, only not as soft as in the mixing stage. It felt twice as loud and made the seats rattle, which also wasn't the effect I wanted.

Comment: I agreed with the practice of Rolling Off of everything above "X"
on your discreet LFE channels (I set mine to 125Hz). Otherwise you're sending excessive signal to the sub and it will get muddy and lack definition and punch.

Answer (score 1):

I infer that you´re talking about a surround mix. Generally, I try to think about what makes my body vibrate to certain sounds in real life and use that. Train tracks, strong footsteps, music in a club. Explosions are a great way to exploit it as well. Start the explosion with a lot of mids to get the crack and end with a lot of low end to carry it through. You say you're not very experienced, so maybe you are talking about a stereo mix. I would be very careful about it. Try to think about how many people will listen through a subwoofer in a properly set up system. Not many. Most will hear them through laptop speakers or tv speakers, so use them to hear the effect that the subwoofer is having.

Comment: Hey Xavier. Yeah, I was referring to 5.1 film mixes. Is there a general starting point you set your crossovers?

Comment: Hey, sorry for taking so long. I think there is some controversy regarding that. I think that audiophiles started recommending higher crossover frequency settings for a home studio setup, and, I`m not to sure about this, but I think that some tv mixes are being done this way. If you're mixing for a theater release, I would advise on a lower frequency range, since theaters have a hard enough time with standing waves already. A lot of people actually sort of bypass the crossover settings for a filter in the lfe channel. I think that that is a better idea and is what I use, since it offers more

Comment: control over your mix. Hope this helps. I meant bypass settings but I meant use a higher frequency and then play with a filter. Crossovers are generally harsher. It depends on what kind of movie and where it will be shown, etc. Morten Green has also a great answer. Just do all of the cross referencing you possibly can and trust your ears. That is the best advice I was given.

Answer (score 1):

"less is more"?

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason why we have THX and Dolby certified rooms!  Dub stages are for mixing theatrical releases.  If you're trying to mix a theatrical release in a small room your results will never be as intended.